# Wunderlist.com REST-API

Tags: javascript, http, api, rest

Как провести авторизацию на wunderlist.com и использовать api?
Читал https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation -попробовал- не выходит
 Я создал приложение и заходил с моим паролем и почтой, но по-видимому не туда,куда надо. 
Можете пожалуйста описать, как вообще происходит авторизация и дальнейшая работа? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В документации все написано.

Сначала переходите по ссылке в браузере

```
https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=URL&state=RANDOM_STRING
```

Потом сервер перенаправит вас на указанный redirect_uri и передаст параметр code, а так же state который вы указали в url. Параметр код необходимо запомнить для следующего шага.

Далее вам необходимо сделать POST запрос на

```
https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/access_token
```

передав туда параметры

`{
  client_id:ID приложения,
  client_secret:Секретный ключ приложения,
  code: Полученый параметр code
}`

Если все гуд в ответе получите access_token

`{
  "access_token": "976d16a81ccf621a654fcc23193b09498b220e89eb72ced3"
}`

Далее в заголовках ко все запросам отправляйте этот токен и client_id

`X-Access-Token: ACCESS_TOKEN
 X-Client-ID: CLIENT-ID`

Comment: а что надо указывать в state redirect_url ?Тоесть надо на сервере у меня создать приёмник по адресу редиректа и принимать, что туда прийдёт и потом подставлять полученный токен? А что значит тогда токен самого приложения, который уже известен?

Comment: У вас есть Client_SECRET - скорее всего это и есть токен приложения.
Да, на сервере нужен "приемник", который возьмет полученый code, и отправит post запрос, потом получит клиентский access_token и сохранит у себя.